# A text editor that we can bookmark in it

Tags: text-editor

Is there any text editor that I can use Bookmarks in it? similar to the bookmarks we can put on lines of code in VisualStudio editor. Does NotePad++ or other editors have this ability?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notepad++ has bookmarks as standard. Just click to the right of the line number and a little blue dot appears to show the line is bookmarked. The bookmarks menu is under `Search -> Bookmark`.

**Default shortcut keys:**
Toggle Bookmark: Ctrl+F2
Next Bookmark: F2
Prev Bookmark: Shift+F2

<strike>Unfortunately, bookmarks don't persist after closing files.</strike> Actually, you can save bookmarks automatically: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/26dfa49d

Comment: Can we see all the bookmarks at one place?

Answer (score 1):

The Boxer Text Editor has bookmark capability. See Boxer Software's website.